# SingleSelect still holds a selected item despite that item being filtered out from display in the grid (Vaadin 14)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

When the user selects an item is a `Grid`, we can retrieve the object represented by that item's row.

For example, in a [`Grid< LocalDate`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) named `grid` holding some [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects, we can access the [`SingleSelect`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/selection/SingleSelect.html) object representing the current selection.

```
LocalDate localDate = grid.asSingleSelect().getValue() ;
```

If no row in the grid is selected, the `localDate` in line above will be null.

If a [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) has a filter applied to its [`DataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/DataProvider.html), the display of some or all rows may be suppressed to match the items in the data provider that do not pass the predicate test of the filter.

When the filter is activated, and rows are suppressed from display, and the currently selected row is among them, the grid is left displaying some rows. None of the displayed rows is selected. So I would expect the `SingleSelect` object to have been updated, to report its value as `null`.

The problem is that [`SingleSelect`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/selection/SingleSelect.html) is *not* updated in such a case. The `SingleSelect` continues to report its value as an item no longer displayed within the grid.

➥ Is this a bug or a feature? Does [`SingleSelect`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/selection/SingleSelect.html) holding a value for an item not appearing on screen make sense?

➥ If a feature rather than bug, then how should I go about clearing other content on screen that is related to the technically-selected yet no-longer-displayed grid item?

I ran into this problem because, in my real work, I had a a detail form showing details of the selected item in the grid. My change listener for the data provider fires when the filters are activated. When the previously selected row disappears from view after filtering, my listener went to test the `SingleSelect` of the grid to see if a row was no longer selected so that I I could clear my detail form by setting its binder bean to null. I was surprised that `SingleSelect` still held a selected item despite that item being filtered out from display in the grid.

```
    dataProvider.addDataProviderListener( ( DataChangeEvent < Invoice > dataChangeEvent ) -> {
        if( this.grid.asSingleSelect().isEmpty()) {   //  Surprise! Not empty despite no selected item currently displayed in `Grid`. 
            invoiceDetailPane.binder.setBean( null );
        }
    } );
```

---

Here is a complete app, as simple little demo of the behavior.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.IntegerField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.ListDataProvider;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
@CssImport ( "./styles/shared-styles.css" )
@CssImport ( value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    private Grid < LocalDate > grid;
    private IntegerField yearField;
    private Button tellSelectGetValue;

    public MainView ( )
    {
        yearField = new IntegerField( "Filter years before: " );
        yearField.addValueChangeListener(
                ( AbstractField.ComponentValueChangeEvent < IntegerField, Integer > event ) -> {
                    Integer year = event.getValue();
                    // If the user cleared the field, its value is null. In such a case, clear all filters.
                    // If the user entered a year number into this field, specify a filter.
                    if ( Objects.isNull( year ) )
                    {
                        ( ( ListDataProvider < LocalDate > ) grid.getDataProvider() ).clearFilters();
                    } else
                    {
                        ( ( ListDataProvider < LocalDate > ) grid.getDataProvider() ).setFilter( ( LocalDate localDate ) -> localDate.getYear() < year );
                    }
                }
        );

        tellSelectGetValue = new Button( "SingleSelect.getValue()" );
        tellSelectGetValue.addClickListener(
                ( ClickEvent < Button > clickEvent ) -> {
                    Notification.show( "grid.asSingleSelect().getValue() is " + grid.asSingleSelect().getValue() );
                }
        );

        grid = new Grid <>();
        List < LocalDate > dates = List.of(
                LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
                LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.FEBRUARY , 24 ) ,
                LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.MARCH , 25 ) ,
                LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.APRIL , 26 )
        );
        grid.setItems( new ArrayList < LocalDate >( dates ) );
        grid.addColumn( LocalDate :: toString );
        grid.addColumn( LocalDate :: getYear );
        grid.addColumn( LocalDate :: getDayOfWeek );


        this.add( yearField , tellSelectGetValue , grid );
    }
}
```

Before filtering by year:

[image: screenshot before filtering]

After filtering away selected year, `SingleSelect` continues to report it as selected. Notice the Notification displayed in lower right corner, as a result of clicking the button.

[image: screenshot after filtering]

Comment: The grid can not know if the selected item is still in the data set without fetching all rows. For a `ListDataProvider`, fetching all rows is not an issue, but in the general case where the data provider may or may not be lazily loaded, fetching all items is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with the comment of Erik Lumme:

> The grid cannot know if the selected item is still in the data set
>   without fetching all rows. For a ListDataProvider, fetching all rows
>   is not an issue, but in the general case where the data provider may
>   or may not be lazily loaded, fetching all items is not an option.

Also, I wouldn't recommend to use a `DataProviderListener` for your item details update. IMO the grid's `addSelectionListener` is more suitable. It will fire every time the selection in grid changes, even when changed by code (but can be distinguished by `isFromClient` method). However, you will need to explicitly clear the selection in grid when filter is changing and the previous selected item doesn't match.